# Is this still a correct Taylor expansion?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

We know first-order Taylor expansion:
$$
f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + O(\|x-a\|^2)
$$
If we take negative on both sides and rearrange terms, we may get:
$$
f(a) = f(x) + f'(a)(a-x) + O(\|x-a\|^2).
$$
Notice that the derivative $f'$ is evaluated at $a$ instead of $x$ now, but our expansion point in the second expansion is at the point $x$. Is the second expansion still correct? Feel like nobody ever told me the derivative does not have to be evaluated at the expansion point...

**Remark 1**

Thank everyone for helping me with this question from many perspectives.

I came up with this question when I was reading a statistical tutorial regarding von Mises expansion, where they treat it as a generalization of Taylor expansion. Specifically, equation (5) in https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06469. Surprisingly, people in that field find an expansion of the second form is of more technical convenience for their purpose.

Comment: Taylor polynomials can be thought of as [Birkhoff Interpolation Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_interpolation). One may observe that $$f(x)\approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0+h)(x - x_0),$$ in fact, this approximation is $O(h^3)$ at $x_0+2h$ and $O(h^2)$ elsewhere; in particular, at $x_0 + h$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, but there does not seem to be much merit in rearranging the formula this way. Typically we use Taylor expansions to gain information about $f$ at $x$ from information about $f$ at another point $a$. The way you wrote it,
$$f(a) = f(x) + f'(a)(a-x) + O(\|x-a\|^2)$$
to get information about $f$ at $a$ we need to know $f'(a)$, and if we know $f'(a)$ we likely know $f(a)$ in the first place. Written in the usual way as in your first formula,
$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + O(\|x-a\|^2)$$
we get information about $f$ at $x$ using only information about $f$ at the other point $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, it is still the (manipulated) Taylor expansion around point $a$, since the derivative is evaluated at that point.